# Viewpager PageTransformer animation both background to foreground and foreground to background?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-pageradapter, android-pagetransformer

I implemented viewpager with transformer animation but here is different animation apply this Background To Foreground and Foreground To Background.

```
viewPagerAddToCart.setPageTransformer(true, new BackgroundToForegroundTransformer());
```

And also to different Foreground To Background

```
viewPagerAddToCart.setPageTransformer(true, new ForegroundToBackgroundTransformer());
```

But i need to both together.

I used this library https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers but here it is separate animation not in combine animation.

So, Android people plz help how to use both animation as same time left to right and right to left.

Thank You!

Comment: then pass your custom class implementing `PageTransformer` interface and inside `transformPage` apply those two `PageTransformer`s

Comment: can u explain code

Comment: `class MyPageTransformer implements PageTransformer { ...`

Comment: Yes.. thanks and give me code inside transformPage ?

Comment: `pageTransformer1.transformPage(...); pageTransformer2.transformPage(...);`

Comment: Please post full code because of I will be understand .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157428/discussion-between-najib-puthawala-and-pskink).

Comment: Any one answer please for this question ??

Comment: so did you call `transformPage` of both transformers? like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913931/viewpager-pagetransformer-animation-both-background-to-foreground-and-foreground?noredirect=1#comment80798251_46913931) ?

Comment: I am not understand what u said. Can u please post your code what u said.?

Comment: this is my code
 BaseTransformer  baseTransformer1 = new BackgroundToForegroundTransformer();
        BaseTransformer  baseTransformer2 = new ForegroundToBackgroundTransformer();

        viewPagerAddToCart.setPageTransformer(true, new BackgroundToForegroundTransformer());
        viewPagerAddToCart.setPageTransformer(true, new ForegroundToBackgroundTransformer());

Comment: where is `class MyPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {` ???

Comment: After then what code post here ???

Comment: Which one view passed in this method pageTransformer1.transformPage(...); ??

Comment: I need the solution.. tell me your best answer.